# Blur Container with all seeMore button

Tags: javascript, toggle, selectors-api

Am coding web interface that allow user to clic some content to expand it and see more détails.
Here My Js code

```
Const seeMoreBtn =      document.querySelectorAll('seeMoteBtn');
    For(let i=0; i<seeMoreBtn.length; i++){
      seeMoreBtn[i].addEventListener('click',    ()=>{
       document.getElementById('container').classList.    toggle('active');
      });
    }
```

no error and no active class assigned to container

Comment: Please share the relavents parts of your HTML code (esp. for the `container`) as well. And I suppose, it's intentional, that you have multiple "see more" buttons, but just one container with details?